# Can I use norse mythology in my fantasy world?

Tags: religion, gods

I wonder if I could use these gods and goddesses in my fantasy world or if it's better to create my own religion

Comment: Legally you can, but they're not really the norse gods/goddesses, but really christianized versions. I generally think that making your own is better but that requires you know about that stuff to begin with ^.^

Comment: @Durakken "but they're not really the norse gods/goddesses, but really christianized versions." ??

Comment: @J.Doe We know very little about the original forms of most germanic religions because they were secret or historians at that point didn't care to record stuff down without bias and then when Chistianity wrote it down they were purposefully saying "oh that is like this in our religion so it's the same so believe our religion" warping it ever more so as time went on that by the time it was at all thought to write it down the original mythology was mostly lost.

Comment: @Durakken The professors I have heard speak about Norse culture did not suggest this was the case, though mythology was a secondary topic. Instead, he said the real issue with Norse is the history, as they recorded their history in poetic, sometimes exaggerated sagas that focused on big events without extensive context, and most of the history was thus from the perspective of people the Norse raided. Those concerns are not present in mythological sagas, which can be trusted as accurate as far back as our sources go.

Comment: @J.Doe Almost no one wrote down history and so saying that is a differentiator is just nonsense. We have the same type of historical knowledge of most peoples. What we know of Norse culture come from the incomplete edas, biased "historians", and reconstructions based on various scraps. that all mostly comes from post-christian influences or people who wouldn't know or didn't take accuracy as a thing to aim for. So we know very little about those religions, but its not important for the general pubic which uses their own warped pop-culture version anyways.

Comment: @Durakken "Almost no one wrote down history" ?? I'm afraid your opinion of us having no idea about Norse culture is not shared by historians. They admit that many of our sources are biased, and that need to keep in mind, but your premise that we have no idea is simply not the case. If it were, we could not trust that Alexander the Great existed, as all the sources we have on him are a few hundred years after the fact. I don't know why you consider the Sagas to be of no account, that they can't be considered worth anything in telling us about Norse Mythology, but I'll leave you to your opinion.

Comment: Gods and that are not sole property of a single religion, most based on other beings from different mythologies; creating your own deities and inter-mixing them with Norse beliefs is entirely acceptable and actually could pay off- literature is good that way. :)

Comment: @J.Doe the problem is that what you're talking about is from a culture purposely warping the culture you're trying to figure out and long after it has ceased to really exist and they didn't know what it was like in the first place to be warping it, so they are warping their own wrong ideas of what it was which you are taking as fact. It's like reading the Mothers againsts comics history of comics based on the Comic Code authority and deducing that what Gotham and Metropolis were like. It just doesn't work. You might get a small inkling of fact, but the vast majority is so wrong its laughable

Comment: @Durakken Historians I've learned from who focus in this area do not considered it so devastating as you do. Not by any means. You're welcome to your opinion.

Comment: No. Odin would kill you lightning if you do (and don't share the royalties :-p).

Comment: I put this on hold because the answer to "can I?" boils down to "nobody can stop you".  I mean, it's not like you'd be violating somebody's copyright or trademark.  If you [edit] to describe your goals, you could then ask about using Norse gods or your own to meet those goals.

Answer (score 3):

The key to answering this, I think, is to answer the question:

**Is the religion a central part of the story you are telling?**

If it is, then you should spend the time and effort to make it just right for your world and the story you are telling. If some existing religion (historic or modern) provides a good starting point for this, then it's fine to use it -- nobody owns the property rights to the Norse deities, for example -- but you should **take the time to adapt it to your world and your story's needs.**

If the religion is *not* a central part of the story you are telling, but rather a side element that perhaps isn't even directly shown in the story, then it's probably better to **spend the time and effort to refine the parts of your world that define *your* world** to the readers. In this case, you may want to copy an existing religion wholesale and maybe just change some names and things like that. It's not going to be showing through much anyway.

Generally speaking, **spend the time defining the elements of your world that define your world.** For the rest, go with something readily available, and maybe make small adjustments as needed. Except for the most hard-core of worldbuilders, building *everything* from scratch is simply not feasible, at least not if you want to get around to actually telling a story.

Answer (score 2):

You can, of course, do both. Use Norse mythology and create your gods and goddesses alongside them. Alternatively, this is again having it both ways, use Norse mythological deities as templates, changing their names initially and gradually reworking their histories, backgrounds and relationships to suit your fantasy world. If you still want to use Norse mythology, there is absolutely nothing to stop you from creating your own version of the Norse deities.

It's your world and you free to do whatever you want to do with it. But always remember to have fun doing it.

Answer (score 2):

(This serves as more of an extension of some of the comments that are arising...)

Throughout history, there have been many instances where the Gods and Goddesses of different religions have either converged or interchanged to make new belief systems.

Both the Ancient Greek and Roman civilisations were on a whole polytheistic, using literally dozens of deities to make sense of the world; as a result, each culture had different versions of the same god with different names/depictions; for instance, each had a "God of War", which Roman mythology named Mars and Greek mythology labeled Ares; similarly the Greek God of love was Aphrodite, the Roman: Venus.

As the two cultures - The Romans predominately - drew influence from one another, they inter-mixed their mythologies, in effect "trading" gods and making up entirely new ones based on the others ideas, to refine their own ideologies further.

---

In conclusion, when we look back through history, we find that religion, gods and myths do not *just* belong to a single civilisation; they do not *just"* belong to a single ideology even, but rather are a product of an inter-mixing of ideas, opinions and clashes of belief.

So really, of course it is acceptable for you to use Norse Gods in your tale of gory despair and gallant bloodthirsty heroism (or like, something completely not violent?)for the religion is not "Copy Righted" per-se (the topic not reserved *just* for those few practicing Nordic goat-herders in the middle of the mountains).

In addition, incorporating  your own versions of deities into the existing mythology, or creating some of your own, will give your story greater depth and an enhanced originality; I personally think this would be a great way of establishing a back story, or even just serve as a cool discussion point somewhere down the line. So yeah. Just do it :P.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly you could. It would be especially good in a fantasy world based around Norse culture and Norse superstition. In a fantasy world that is obviously a different world, it will seem a bit odd if they're the only thing from our own world, but there are ways to justify this.

For example, you could say the gods just have another world they're also managing, or maybe after Ragnarok they had so much fun they wanted to do it again. That would make them the centre of the setting, the true deities, of course.

Another way is simply to have the Norse in your world, even if the other cultures and factions are not from our world. Or, really, you can just have Thor and Odin without explaining why they are there.

Answer (score 1):

### This is a Matter of Opinion

Using Norse mythology or basing your religion off of it will save you time and work, so you can focus on other aspects of the world

But copying an existing religion exactly may bore your readers, colleagues, whoever interracts with your work, etc. so designing a new one might be best.

Answer (score 1):

Both are good. I recommend that if you try to  recreate a Norse or Greek society and mythical creatures, that you use there gods.

If you want to create your own societies and mythical creatures then you should create your own gods.